# Specifying column height

Tags: beamer, columns

I am using the following lines to create two columns

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

I'd like to set the heights of both columns to same value.
How can this be done?

`0.5\textwidth` fixes the column width. I tried,
`\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth,0.2\paperheight}`.

It didn't work. Could someone help?

Comment: Please, provide a complete MWE.

Comment: why you need to define columns' height? their heights is dependent on their contents. what should happen if the content is larger than reserved space? i miss context for your question.

Comment: @Zarko: You need to be able to specify the columns height if you want to use \vfill to align content at both the bottom or top, rather than having one or both of the vertical directions ragged. Think of this as the vertical analogue of left/right/justifying the text. Obviously if the content is too tall, we'd want to the column to overflow with a warning. I suspect the solution involves minipages anyway, so we'd get whatever behavior minipages exhibit on overflow.

Comment: @MRule, after two years ...  what OP like to have, can (now) be done by use of relative new `tabularray` package (if I understood question correctly).  However, about this question is not clear (that is reason that it is closed) nor your comment clarify it). Some sketch of desired table might  be helpful,

Comment: Ok, it's completely clear to me since I use this design pattern all the time in my Beamer slides and posters. I might suggest that this will also be clear to other Beamer users. And the accepted answer that uses `minipage` clarifies it further. It is not an especially confusing question, IMO.

Comment: @MRule Not sure editing the question in such a way that it basically invalids Åke's answer is a good idea....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. multicol**

Here is a solution using [multicols](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), because initially I had no reference to the package that has the definition of the environment `column` and `columns`.

I have added a `minipage` of fixed height and width inside the columns, and the text inside the `minipage`. You can just copy and paste the `minipage`-code inside your "column", and it should work. Uncomment the `%\vspace{-\topskip}` if you want the content to align at the absolute top of the `minipage`. You may also change `\columnwidth`to `0.5\textwidth` if you want the text closer. `\paperheight` also works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][t]{\columnwidth}
%\vspace{-\topskip}%
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here 
\end{minipage}

\columnbreak

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][t]{\columnwidth}
%\vspace{-\topskip}%
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here 
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols}

New text outside the columns starts here and as you see the text is below both columns.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2. beamer**

It also works with [beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) and `columns`. I had to increase the text height to 0.5, because your text was more than `0.2\textheight` (and also more than `0.2\paperheight`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{minipage}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
New text outside the columns starts here and as you see the text is below both columns.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are top aligned, they will look as if they have the same height (even if they don't actually have it). It makes no sense to add additional minipages inside the columns, because they are minipages themselves.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It make sense to put minipage inside the column to force them to be of a specific height. We do not know what Natasha wants to achieve. Add some text after the columns as I did, and you will see the difference.